# .vimrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: vim

I'm trying to configured Vim. However when I try to source `.vimrc` after having edit the file I get the following error:

> $ source ~/.vimrc
>   -bash: let g:plug_shallow = 0                        : command not found
>   -bash: /Users/stevenaguilar/.vimrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   -bash: /Users/stevenaguilar/.vimrc: line 4:`call plug#begin()'

I don't understand where is this error coming from. It throws the error on line `call plug#begin()` which is closed. Here is the full `.vimrc`

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
let g:plug_shallow = 0 " disable shallow cloning

call plug#begin()

Plug 'airblade/vim-gitgutter'                 " shows a git diff in the gutter
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'       " precision colorscheme
Plug 'godlygeek/tabular'                      " text filtering and alignment
Plug 'janko-m/vim-test'                       " test runner
Plug 'phallstrom/vim-sailfish'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'                    " tree explorer
Plug 'sjl/gundo.vim'                          " graph your vim undo tree
Plug 'tpope/vim-commentary'                   " comment stuff out
Plug 'tpope/vim-endwise'                      " wisely add 'end' in ruby, endfunction/endif/more in vim script, etc
Plug 'tpope/vim-fugitive'                     " git wrapper
Plug 'tpope/vim-rails', { 'for': ['ruby'] }   " ruby on rails power tools
Plug 'vim-ruby/vim-ruby', { 'for': ['ruby'] } " vim/ruby configuration
Plug 'tpope/vim-projectionist'                " project configuration (file jumping)
Plug 'kana/vim-textobj-user'                  " create your own text objects
Plug 'nelstrom/vim-textobj-rubyblock'         " custom text object for selecting ruby blocks
Plug 'tpope/vim-surround'                     " quoting/parenthesizing made simple
Plug 'chriskempson/base16-vim'                " color schemes, https://chriskempson.github.io/base16/
Plug 'w0rp/ale'                               " asynchronous lint engine
Plug 'editorconfig/editorconfig-vim'          " editorConfig plugin
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'                " status/tabline
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline-themes'         " status/tabline themes
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'                " Javascript syntax
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'                            " react jsx syntax
Plug 'posva/vim-vue', { 'for': ['vue'] }      " Vue.js syntax
Plug '/usr/local/opt/fzf' | Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim' " A command-line fuzzy finder written in Go
Plug 'kien/rainbow_parentheses.vim', { 'for': ['clojure'] } " Better Rainbow Parentheses
Plug 'guns/vim-clojure-static', { 'for': ['clojure'] } " Meikel Brandmeyer's excellent Clojure runtime files
Plug 'tpope/vim-unimpaired'                   " pairs of handy bracket mappings
Plug 'tpope/vim-abolish'                      " easily search for, substitute, and abbreviate multiple variants of a word
Plug 'mechatroner/rainbow_csv'                " highlighting columns in csv/tsv files
Plug 'slim-template/vim-slim' " slim syntax highlighting for vim

call plug#end()
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""

set t_Co=256

set nocompatible      " We're running Vim, not Vi!
set synmaxcol=500     " don't try to highlight long lines
compiler ruby         " Enable compiler support for ruby

filetype plugin on

set background=dark
colorscheme base16-oceanicnext

set backspace=2
set expandtab
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 softtabstop=2
set autoindent
set nowrap
set nrformats=

set backupdir=$HOME/.vimbackup,.
set directory=$HOME/.vimswap,.

au FocusLost * :wa

set ignorecase
set smartcase
set scrolloff=2
set ttyfast
set hidden
set wildmenu
set wildmode=list:longest
nnoremap <leader>nt :NERDTreeToggle<enter>

source $VIMRUNTIME/macros/matchit.vim

" fzf
nnoremap <silent> <C-p> :Files<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Leader>b :Buffers<CR>

" https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/commit/4dcfc318e0b02fdbb0c2d9ff77cf3562b46eea25
xmap \\  <Plug>Commentary
nmap \\  <Plug>Commentary

set updatetime=250

nmap <silent> <leader>s :TestNearest<CR>
nmap <silent> <leader>t :TestFile<CR>
nmap <silent> <leader>T :TestSuite<CR>

set mouse=a
vnoremap <Leader>c "*y
noremap <Leader>v "*p

set nofixeol

set formatoptions+=j " Delete comment character when joining commented lines

au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
    \ exe "normal g'\"" | endif

let g:omni_sql_no_default_maps = 1 " disable SQL autocompletion entirely

" To ensure that EditorConfig plugin works well with Tim Pope's fugitive
let g:EditorConfig_exclude_patterns = ['fugitive://.*']

" ALE - Asynchronous Lint Engine
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 0        " no checks on open
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1         " check on save
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 1 " check on text change
let g:ale_lint_delay = 300         " millisecond delay before checking

" Airline
let g:airline_theme = 'base16'                  " theme
set laststatus=2                                " always show airline
set noshowmode                                  " hide default mode indicator
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1               " use powerline font
let g:airline#extensions#wordcount#enabled = 0  " disable word counting
let g:airline#extensions#whitespace#enabled = 0 " disable detection of whitespace errors

if filereadable($HOME."/.vimrc_local")
  source $HOME/.vimrc_local
endif

let g:jsx_ext_required = 0 " JSX syntax in .js files

" open file splits in vsplit by default
:nnoremap <C-W>f :vertical wincmd f<CR>

" https://github.com/posva/vim-vue#how-can-i-use-existing-configurationplugins-in-vue-files
" autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.vue setlocal filetype=vue.html.javascript.css

au FileType clojure exe "RainbowParenthesesLoadRound" | RainbowParenthesesActivate

" open NERDTree automatically when vim starts up on opening a directory
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in") | exe 'NERDTree' argv()[0] | wincmd p | ene | endif

" https://github.com/slim-template/vim-slim/issues/38#issuecomment-23760100
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.slim setlocal filetype=slim
```

Comment: You aren't supposed to source your `.vimrc` from bash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+source+%7E%2F.vimrc+bash+syntax+error

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you're sourcing your .vimrc from bash. It's not a bash script. Instead, you should source it from inside Vim:

```
:source ~/.vimrc
:source $MYVIMRC
```

Or just restart Vim.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are trying to source your `.vimrc` from bash as you would your `.bashrc`, but this is a vim-specific settings file.  vim will naturally source your `.vimrc` when you run it, if it is in the right place in your path (which it seems to be based on the error message).

If you are already in vim and have made some changes to the `.vimrc` or wish to load another one, you can source it from within vim by going into command mode and calling source

```
:source ~/.vimrc
```