# My VIM configuration doesn't work with autocmd plugin

Tags: vim

```
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab
set nu
set autoindent
set cindent
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf-8,ucs-bom,gb18030,gbk,gb2312,cp936
set termencoding=utf-8
filetype plugin indent on
autocmd Filetype python setlocal expandtab tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

I added the last two lines into .vimrc but received this error message:

```
-bash: filetype: command not found
-bash: autocmd: command not found
```

I haven't used this plugin before and what's the proper way to enable it? My purpose is to avoid the error message when I edit a file with vim on a Linux machine remotely:

```
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.vimrc: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token \`('](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413694/vimrc-line-4-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+bash%3A+filetype%3A+command+not+found

Answer (score 1):

```
-bash: filetype: command not found
-bash: autocmd: command not found
```

These errors seem to be printed by **bash**,
did you run something like `source .vimrc`?

Comment: Yes, when I run source ~/.vimrc, it prints this error message.